# Pipe output of more than one variable using tidyr::map or dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am building upon my earlier question on SO at [Pipe output of one data.frame to another using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435203/pipe-output-of-one-data-frame-to-another-using-dplyr)

I want to create six correlation matrices that would let me analyze evolution of correlation in $ spent and quantity sold in the last three years. In essence, I am looking for `2 X [3X3]` type list. So far, I am able to create `3X3` list using `tidyr::map()` by making separate calls for each `Product_Type` and `Quantity`, but I have been unsuccessful in doing in one vectorized call. As you will see below, there is a lot of redundancy in my code.

Here's my data:

```
dput(DFile_Gather)
structure(list(Order.ID = c(456, 567, 345, 567, 2345, 8910, 8910, 
789, 678, 456, 345, 8910, 234, 1234, 456), Calendar.Year = c(2015, 
2015, 2016, 2015, 2017, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2015, 
2016, 2016, 2015), Product_Type = c("Insurance", "Insurance", 
"Tire", "Tire", "Rental", "Insurance", "Servicing", "Truck", 
"Tire", "Servicing", "Truck", "Rental", "Car", "Servicing", "Tire"
), Mexican_Pesos = c(35797.32, 1916.25, 19898.62, 0, 22548.314011, 
686.88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 203276.65683), Quantity = c(0.845580721440663, 
0.246177053792905, 2.10266268677851, 1.89588258358317, 0.00223077008050406, 
0.454640961140588, 1.92032156606277, 0.475872861771994, 0.587966920885798, 
0.721024745664671, 0.696609684682582, 0.0441522564791413, 0.872232778060772, 
0.343347997825813, 0.716224049425646)), .Names = c("Order.ID", 
"Calendar.Year", "Product_Type", "Mexican_Pesos", "Quantity"), row.names = c(54L, 
55L, 13L, 15L, 50L, 58L, 28L, 37L, 16L, 24L, 33L, 48L, 2L, 29L, 
14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my code for the first iteration : i.e. calculate correlation matrix for Product_Type

```
DFile_Spread_PType <- spread(DFile_Gather[-length(DFile_Gather)],key = Product_Type, value = Mexican_Pesos)

DFile<-DFile_Spread_PType
CYear <- unique(DFile$Calendar.Year)
DFile_Corr_PType <- purrr::map(CYear, ~ dplyr::filter(DFile, Calendar.Year == .)) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ cor(.[,colnames(DFile)[3:length(colnames(DFile))]]) ) %>%
  structure(., names = CYear)
```

Finally, here's my code for the second iteration for Correlation Matrix by Quantity:

```
DFile_Spread_Qty <- spread(subset( DFile_Gather, select = -Mexican_Pesos),key = Product_Type, value = Quantity)
DFile<-DFile_Spread_Qty
DFile_Corr_Qty <- purrr::map(CYear, ~ dplyr::filter(DFile, Calendar.Year == .)) %>% 
  purrr::map(~ cor(.[,colnames(DFile)[3:length(colnames(DFile))]]) ) %>%
  structure(., names = CYear)
```

As you can see above, there is too much redundancy, and the code looks really clunky. 
I would sincerely appreciate if someone could help me out. I am specifically looking for two things:

1) do what I am doing above by not having any redundancy

2) If possible, get a list of 2X3X3 i.e. `Quantity` and `Product_Type` at top level, and then 3x3 correlation matrices referenced to each of the above.

I searched similar topics on SO, but I don't think there was any thread on similar topics.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has no redundancy and uses no packages.  Make `Product_Type` a factor and then split by year giving the list of years `s`.  Now use a double `Map` over `s` and `Values` converting to wide form on each inner iteration using `tapply` and running `cor`.

```
DG <- transform(DFile_Gather, Product_Type = factor(Product_Type))
s <- split(DG, DG$Calendar.Year)
Values <- c("Mexican_Pesos", "Quantity")
By <- c("Order.ID", "Product_Type")
res <- Map(function(v) Map(function(s) cor(tapply(s[, v], s[By], c)), s), Values)
```

Comment: @G Grothendieck - Thanks for your help. This does solve the problem. Very respectfully, do you think you could demystify the last line a little bit? I tried understanding what you have done by executing the statement in parts but I am getting all sort ungodly errors that I don't think I will ever be able to understand. I'd appreciate if you could explain the last statement by breaking it down into executable pieces that could be run on our machine because it's really powerful, and if understood properly, it will help me a lot in the future.

Comment: `tapply(s[, v], v[By], c)`  converts `Mexican_Pesos` or `Quantity` (depending on the value of `v`) for one year of data (depending on `s`) to wide form such that the wide form rows are defined by `By[1]`, i.e. by `Order.ID` and the columns by `By[2]`, i.e. by `Product_Type`.  We take the `cor` of that.  The `cor(tapply(...))` can be thought of as the body of a double loop that iterates over all combinations of `s` and `Values`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the correlations among `Product_Type` for each response variable and year combination, you could reshape your dataset into a convenient format, split the dataset into a list for the combination of factors, and get the correlations via `map` with the help of `dplyr::select` for selecting the columns.  However, this does not return a list of lists.

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

DFile_Gather %>%
    gather(type, value, Mexican_Pesos:Quantity) %>%
    spread(Product_Type, value) %>%
    split(list(.$Calendar.Year, .$type)) %>%
    map(~cor(dplyr::select(.x, Car:Truck)))
```

The list of lists took an extra step, as I had to first `split` by the response variable and then, within each element of that list, `split` by `Calendar.Year`.  Then I used `at_depth` instead of `map` to calculation the correlations across `Product_Type` for each list within the list.  Working at the lowest level is indicated by the `2` in `at_depth`.

```
DFile_Gather %>%
    gather(type, value, Mexican_Pesos:Quantity) %>%
    spread(Product_Type, value) %>%
    split(.$type) %>%
    map(~split(.x, .x$Calendar.Year)) %>%
    at_depth(2, ~cor(dplyr::select(.x, Car:Truck)))
```

The first few rows/columns of the interim dataset after gathering and spreading looks like:

```
   Order.ID Calendar.Year          type       Car    Insurance       Rental
1       234          2016 Mexican_Pesos 0.0000000           NA           NA
2       234          2016      Quantity 0.8722328           NA           NA
3       345          2016 Mexican_Pesos        NA           NA           NA
4       345          2016      Quantity        NA           NA           NA
5       456          2015 Mexican_Pesos        NA 3.579732e+04           NA
6       456          2015      Quantity        NA 8.455807e-01           NA
...
```